# Convert numpy object array to sparse matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, scipy

I would like to convert a numpy array with `dtype=object` to a sparse array e.g. `csr_matrix`. However, this fails.

```
x = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype=object)

csr_matrix(x) # This fails
csc_matrix(x) # This fails
```

Both of the calls to sparse matrices produce the following error:

> TypeError: no supported conversion for types: (dtype('O'),)

In fact, even calling

```
csr_matrix(['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

produces the same error. Do sparse matrices not support `object` dtypes?

Comment: Can a sparse matrix contain non numerical elements ?

Comment: What is a `zero` element in object dtype? The `csr` math won't work with objects. It is compiled with a limited set of numeric types. What do you expect to do with such a matrix?  Even strings don't work.

Comment: Well, I would expect `None` to be the `zero` element. However, it does make sense to only work with numeric types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to create a `coo` format matrix from your `x`:

```
In [22]: x = np.array([['a', 'b', 'c']], dtype=object)
In [23]: M=sparse.coo_matrix(x)
In [24]: M
Out[24]: 
<1x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.object_'>'
    with 3 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [25]: M.data
Out[25]: array(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype=object)
```

`coo` has just flattened the input array and assigned it to its `data` attribute.  (`row` and `col` have the indices).

```
In [31]: M=sparse.coo_matrix(x)
In [32]: print(M)
  (0, 0)    a
  (0, 1)    b
  (0, 2)    c
```

But displaying it as an array produces an error.

```
In [26]: M.toarray()
ValueError: unsupported data types in input
```

Trying to convert it to other formats produces your `typeerror`.

`dok` sort of works:

```
In [28]: M=sparse.dok_matrix(x)
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/sputils.py:114: UserWarning: object dtype is not supported by sparse matrices
  warnings.warn("object dtype is not supported by sparse matrices")
In [29]: M
Out[29]: 
<1x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.object_'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Dictionary Of Keys format>
```

String dtype works a little better, `x.astype('U1')`, but still has problems with conversion to `csr`.

Sparse matrices were developed for large linear algebra problems.  The ability to do matrix multiplication and linear equation solution were most important. Their application to non-numeric tasks is recent, and incomplete.

Comment: Thanks for the insightful follow-up!

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is supported and while the documents are a bit sparse on this end, [this part of the sources](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/sparse/generate_sparsetools.py#L137) should show that:

```
# List of the supported data typenums and the corresponding C++ types
#
T_TYPES = [
    ('NPY_BOOL', 'npy_bool_wrapper'),
    ('NPY_BYTE', 'npy_byte'),
    ('NPY_UBYTE', 'npy_ubyte'),
    ('NPY_SHORT', 'npy_short'),
    ('NPY_USHORT', 'npy_ushort'),
    ('NPY_INT', 'npy_int'),
    ('NPY_UINT', 'npy_uint'),
    ('NPY_LONG', 'npy_long'),
    ('NPY_ULONG', 'npy_ulong'),
    ('NPY_LONGLONG', 'npy_longlong'),
    ('NPY_ULONGLONG', 'npy_ulonglong'),
    ('NPY_FLOAT', 'npy_float'),
    ('NPY_DOUBLE', 'npy_double'),
    ('NPY_LONGDOUBLE', 'npy_longdouble'),
    ('NPY_CFLOAT', 'npy_cfloat_wrapper'),
    ('NPY_CDOUBLE', 'npy_cdouble_wrapper'),
    ('NPY_CLONGDOUBLE', 'npy_clongdouble_wrapper'),
]
```

Asking for object-based types sounds like a lot. Even some more basic types like [float16](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/7408) are missing.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I was quite puzzled at this behaviour, and I guessed it must be something like this. Thanks for confirming!